# Is it possible to see a remote's remotes in git?

Tags: git

I have a local `git clone` of a repo. I can of course see my local remote, `origin` using `git remote`. However, can I see the remotes for my remote, `origin`? Can I see any details about those remotes, such as the URL?

Comment: So you want to see what remotes are configured on another repository? I don't know of a way to do that. Typically I would visit the other clone (via ssh if on another machine) and use `git remote -v` there locally. If I don't have the right to visit the other clone, then I probably also don't have the authorization to view its configuration.

Comment: @Raffael - yes, exactly. That is all my assumption, too, but `git` has many nooks and crannies, so I thought I'd ask. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in general, other than via the method in the comment (`ssh` to the server and run `git remote` there).

You can, however, see all<sup>1</sup> of the remote's *references*, including its own remote-tracking branches, and from this information you can make some good guesses:

```
$ git ls-remote
From ssh:[redacted]
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f    HEAD
222c4dd303570d096f0346c3cd1dff6ea2c84f83    refs/heads/branch
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f    refs/heads/master
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f    refs/remotes/foo/bar
d41117433d7b4431a188c0eddec878646bf399c3    refs/tags/tag-foo
```

The above implies that the machine in question must have a remote named `foo` (from which it got branch `bar`, renamed to `refs/remotes/foo/bar`).  In fact, it doesn't, as I created that remote-tracking branch manually just before this:

```
$ cd ~/tmp/t
$ git update-ref refs/remotes/foo/bar master
$ git for-each-ref
222c4dd303570d096f0346c3cd1dff6ea2c84f83 commit refs/heads/branch
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f commit refs/heads/master
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f commit refs/remotes/foo/bar
d41117433d7b4431a188c0eddec878646bf399c3 commit refs/tags/tag-foo
```

---

<sup>1</sup>A remote can hide particular references now; you actually see only those they permit.  The *default* is to permit all, though.

#### Bugs!  Well, sort of.

Incidentally, along the way I discovered that `git update-ref -d` exits successfully even if it deletes nothing (I used `git update-ref -d` to delete `refs/remotes/foo/bar` but first ran it in wrong repo).  This led to discovering another minor bug:

```
$ nullsha=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
$ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/foo/bar $nullsha || echo bug
```

(no output, good: we "deleted" it successfully while expecting it not to exist in the first place).

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/foo/bar master && echo bug
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/foo/bar': unable to resolve
 reference refs/remotes/foo/bar: No such file or directory
```

Odd: the delete *should* (and did) fail as the ref does not exist, much less match `master`, but that's a pretty weird message.  (Incidentally, I'm breaking up long lines for posting purposes.)

```
$ mastersha=$(git rev-parse master)
$ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/foo/bar $mastersha
```

Same failure message; seems like you can't provide a non-zero expected SHA1 and have a "quiet" failure.  (The actual name-or-SHA-1 is irrelevant except that the all-zero "null hash" means "does not exist", as is generally the case in Git.)

What about creation, can we expect a null-hash to make sure we are the ones creating the ref?

```
$ git update-ref refs/remotes/foo/bar $mastersha $nullsha || echo bug
```

No output, good: it should create only if new, so let's try again and make sure the creation reports a nonzero status:

```
$ git update-ref refs/remotes/foo/bar $mastersha $nullsha && echo bug
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/foo/bar': cannot
 lock ref 'refs/remotes/foo/bar': ref refs/remotes/foo/bar is at
 11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d but expected
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

No actual bug, but another odd message.  This one at least makes *sense* though.

What happens if we ask to delete it, when we expect it to be deleted but it's not?

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/foo/bar $nullsha && echo bug
bug
```

Whoops, we were able to delete it!  So don't try to use the null-hash for this purpose; there's no atomic-delete operation with the null hash, only atomic-create.  (`git update-ref -d` correctly fails if we provide some other valid, but not `$mastersha`, hash; so atomic delete is a two-step operation: parse to get hash, then try to delete using that hash.)

Comment: `git ls-remote` is very interesting. I had to do a review of what git refs are, really, and found [this description](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) to be excellent.

Comment: I tweaked my original question -- can you also see any of the information about your remote's remotes, such as their URLs?

Comment: This part is easy: *can you also see any of the information about your remote's remotes, such as their URLs?*  No.